# How do I combine Google Apps Scripts into 1 to minimize GMAIL API calls?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

I have 9 separate scripts setup to import CSV attachments from GMAIL to Google Sheets every 5 minutes.  I prefer to do this more often, but received a temp ban when trying to execute these every minute.  I would also like to eliminate this error if possible:  `TypeError: Cannot call method "getMessages" of undefined.` which is returned when there is no email present to process.

Is there a way to execute each script together with one GMAIL API call as opposed to 9 separate?  Same email address, different labels per script.
Here's 2 of the 9 scripts executed every 5 minutes:

```
function STSalesImportFromGmail() { 
  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Streeterville Sales').getThreads(0,1);     
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {                            
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Streeterville Sales");
    //parses content of csv to array
    var dataString = attachment.getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(dataString);
    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sh.clearContents().clearFormats();                                         
    //pastes array to sheet
    var lastRowValue = sh.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
       sh.getRange(i+lastRowValue+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    } 
    if( message.getSubject().indexOf('END OF DAY SALES DETAILS') !== -1) {
    STlogTodaysSales()
    }
  //marks the Gmail message as read, unstars it and deletes it using Gmail API (Filter sets a star)
  message.markRead();
  message.unstar();
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", message.getId()); // Added
    }
}
//The code formats the code so it can be entered into the Google Script

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){ 
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +


      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +


      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );


  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;

  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }

    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Streeterville Sales");
  label.deleteLabel();
}
function STLaborImportFromGmail() { 
  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Streeterville Labor').getThreads(0,1);     
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {                            
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Streeterville Labor");
    //parses content of csv to array
    var dataString = attachment.getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(dataString);
    var range = sh.getRange("A:K");
    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
  range.clear();
    //pastes array to sheet
    var lastRowValue = sh.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
       sh.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    } 
    if( message.getSubject().indexOf('END OF WEEK LABOR DETAILS') !== -1) {
    STlogWeeksLabor()
    }
  }

  //marks the Gmail message as read, unstars it and deletes it using Gmail API (Filter sets a star)
  message.markRead();
  message.unstar();
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", message.getId()); // Added

}
function STlogTodaysSales() {
  var todaysSales = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Streeterville Sales Log!STSalesImport');
  var logSheet = todaysSales.getSheet();
  logSheet.appendRow(
    todaysSales.getValues()
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); }) // flatten the 2D array to 1D
  );
}
function STlogWeeksLabor() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Streeterville Labor Log');
  var rg=sh.getRange('STLaborImport');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

```
function SLSalesImportFromGmail() { 
  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('South Loop Sales').getThreads(0,1);     
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {                            
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Sales");
    //parses content of csv to array
    var dataString = attachment.getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(dataString);
    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sh.clearContents().clearFormats();                                         
    //pastes array to sheet
    var lastRowValue = sh.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
       sh.getRange(i+lastRowValue+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    } 
    if( message.getSubject().indexOf('END OF DAY SALES DETAILS') !== -1) {
    SLlogTodaysSales()
    }
  //marks the Gmail message as read, unstars it and deletes it using Gmail API (Filter sets a star)
  message.markRead();
  message.unstar();
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", message.getId()); // Added
    }
}
//The code formats the code so it can be entered into the Google Script

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ){ 
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to comma.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +


      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +


      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );


  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;

  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }

    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("South Loop Sales");
  label.deleteLabel();
}
function SLLaborImportFromGmail() { 
  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('South Loop Labor').getThreads(0,1);     
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {                            
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Labor");
    //parses content of csv to array
    var dataString = attachment.getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(dataString);
    var range = sh.getRange("A:K");
    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
  range.clear();
    //pastes array to sheet
    var lastRowValue = sh.getLastRow();
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
       sh.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    } 
    if( message.getSubject().indexOf('END OF WEEK LABOR DETAILS') !== -1) {
    SLlogWeeksLabor()
    }
  }

  //marks the Gmail message as read, unstars it and deletes it using Gmail API (Filter sets a star)
  message.markRead();
  message.unstar();
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", message.getId()); // Added

}
function SLlogTodaysSales() {
  var todaysSales = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('South Loop Sales Log!SLSalesImport');
  var logSheet = todaysSales.getSheet();
  logSheet.appendRow(
    todaysSales.getValues()
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); }) // flatten the 2D array to 1D
  );
}
function SLlogWeeksLabor() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('South Loop Labor Log');
  var rg=sh.getRange('SLLaborImport');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: Please read [Batching Requests | Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to `threads` being empty.

What you can do to avoid this error is, before trying to use a property of `threads`check if it's `!=null`.

Add a check like this: `if (threads && threads.length>0)` before continuing.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Streeterville Sales').getThreads(0,1);
if(threads) {
   var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
   ...
```

Comment: Tried using this but still receiving the same error.

```
function STSalesImportFromGmail() { 
  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Streeterville Sales').getThreads(0,1);
    if(threads) {
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
    }
```

Comment: Well when I get an error like that I start looking closely at what the error says is undefined.  I think that's where you should look.